# Vuetify VTooltip trigger only on activator click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I wanted to trigger Vuetify tooltip `VTooltip` only when the activator is clicked rather than hovered. I tried to bind it with a variable but still triggered on hover.

```js
 methods: { 

  doCopy(){
     // copy logic
     this.showCopied = true;
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.showCopied = false
      }, 1000)

  }
 }
```

```html
 <VTooltip v-model="showCopied">
    <template #activator="{ on }">
      <VBtn  v-on="on" @click="doCopy"> COPY </VBtn>
    </template>
 </VTooltip>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I have to disable the default event handler of the activator. 
Simply removing default event object `(on)` binding solves the issue.

```html
<VTooltip v-model="showCopied">
    <template #activator={}>
      <VBtn  @click="doCopy"> COPY </VBtn>
    </template>
 </VTooltip>
```

[UPDATED] based on @Kael Watts-Deuchar answer
**NB**: the v-model biding is mandatory

Comment: Thanks for posting as I was just contemplating how to do something similar with a different Vuetify component and came across this.

Comment: `on.prevent` isn't a modifier, it's accessing the `prevent` property on the `on` object, which is undefined. You'd have the same effect by not using v-on at all.

Answer (score 12):

This is actually more complicated than I expected thanks to some bugs. You *should* be able to just do `<v-tooltip :open-on-hover="false">`, but a focus listener is still added which causes the click to close the tooltip immediately. Instead you need to bind the click and blur events separately, and add `retain-focus-on-click` to the button so it doesn't blur immediately.

Full solution:

```html
<v-tooltip bottom :open-on-hover="false">
  <template #activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn @click="on.click" @blur="on.blur" retain-focus-on-click>Copy</v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>Copy</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 1):

In vuetify 2.6.1 you can do it like this now

```html
<v-tooltip
  open-on-click
  :open-on-hover="false"
>
  <template
    v-slot:activator="{ on }"
  >
    <v-btn
      v-on="on"
    >
      button with tooltip
    </v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>tooltip message</span>
</v-tooltip>
```